# WaitForSelector timing out on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, puppeteer

I'm creating a web application that listens for incoming emails using Microsoft Graph, selects some checkboxes and then submits a form. The flow is as follows:

1. Go to https://scheduler.engr.wisc.edu, this redirects me to my University's SSO page.
2. After logging in, the program is redirected to https://scheduler.engr.wisc.edu, where I do the form submission.

Here's the code:

```
exports.itsTimeToVulture = async (droppedShifts) => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://scheduler.engr.wisc.edu/worklocation/detail/1-' +  moment(droppedShifts[0].date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));

  await page.type('#j_username', process.env.USER);
  await page.type('#j_password', process.env.PASS);
  await page.click('button[type=submit]');

  await page.waitForSelector('.footer').then(() => {
    return page.$$eval('.timeslot', (timeslots, week) => {
      week.forEach((day, index) => {
        if (day) {
          day.forEach(shift => {
            timeslots[index].children.item(shift).querySelector('input[name*=schedadd]').setAttribute('checked', true);
          });
        }
      });
    }, getIndices(droppedShifts));
  });

  await page.click('input[type=submit]');
  await browser.close()
};
```

Initially, I tried using `page.waitForNavigation()` but that gave an error. I resolved to using `page.waitForSelector()` and it works perfectly on a local server.

The issue I run into is while using Heroku. I've installed `puppeteer-heroku-buildpack` as well as the `node.js` buildpack. However `waitForSelector()` times out for some reason. Here's the error from my logs:

```
{ TimeoutError: waiting for selector ".footer" failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded
info app web.1 at new WaitTask (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/DOMWorld.js:561:28)
info app web.1 at DOMWorld._waitForSelectorOrXPath (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/DOMWorld.js:490:22)
info app web.1 at DOMWorld.waitForSelector (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/DOMWorld.js:444:17)
info app web.1 at Frame.waitForSelector (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/FrameManager.js:628:47)
info app web.1 at Frame.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:23)
info app web.1 at Page.waitForSelector (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:1046:29)
info app web.1 at exports.itsTimeToVulture (/app/helpers/scraper.js:17:14)
info app web.1 at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) name: 'TimeoutError' }
```

What I find really confusing is that this setup works fine on localhost but fails on heroku. Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Put a `try...catch` around your code and make a screenshot to see what the page looks like when the error happens. This should give you a hint why it's not working.

Comment: Do you mean around the entire function or just `waitForSelector()`? Since I'm running the instance on heroku do you know how I could get the screenshot?

Comment: You are mixing then and async/await syntax in your code. In your case you have to add a `.catch` block to catch the error.

Comment: From the first look, I am assuming the username and password is wrong. I can simply check for the content of the page (`await page.content()`) if not sure how to grab screenshot. Something must be there.

Comment: @ThomasDondorf Dondorf I had initially used `await` for waitForSelector and it did not work. @Md.AbuTaher, I'm ashamed to say that this was the issue. If you post an answer I'll mark it as correct. I was using my own test.env file for development and that had the correct password, but my heroku env var was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and this worked for me:

```
await page.goto("https://www.my-web.com", {timeout: 60000, waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'})
```